# struggle when trying to deploy my project

Tags: machine-learning, flask, deployment

i have created the web app using flask to predict whether the tweet is related or not after i applied the ML algorithm (Trigrams PassiveAgrissive classifier), but i struggled in point that how can i test the value its self after the user writing his tweet, since i have the seperate code for testing with specific chosen tweets:

```
 def most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(vectrizer, classifier, n=100):
          class_labels = classifier.classes_
          feature_names = vectorizer.get_feature_names_out()
          topn_class1 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[:n]
          topn_class2 = sorted(zip(classifier.coef_[0], feature_names))[-n:]
          for coef, feat in topn_class1:
            print(class_labels[0], coef, feat)
          print()
          for coef, feat in reversed(topn_class2):
            print(class_labels[1], coef, feat)
            
            sentences = [
            "Just happened a terrible car crash",
            "Heard about #earthquake is different cities, stay safe everyone.",
            "No I don't like cold!",
            "@RosieGray Now in all sincerety do you think the UN would move to Israel if there was a fraction of a chance of being annihilated?"
        ]
        
            tfidf_trigram = tfidf_vectorizer3.transform(sentences)
            predictions = pass_tf_trigram.predict(tfidf_trigram)
            for text, label in zip(sentences, predictions):
                if label==1:
                    target="Disaster Tweet"
                    print("text:", text, "\nClass:", target)
                    print()
            else:
                target="Normal Tweet"
                print("text:", text, "\nClass:", target)
                print()

   most_informative_feature_for_binary_classification(tfidf_vectorizer_3, pass_tf_trigram, n=100)
```

and this was works successfully, but the demand goal is test the entered tweet by user

model.py

```
#%%
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import pickle

# Load the csv file
df = pd.read_csv("C:\\Users\\LENOVO\\Desktop\\animated-template\\Deploy\\df.csv")

print(df.head())

# Select independent and dependent variable
x= df.cleaned_tweets
y = df.target

# Split the dataset into train and test
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x,y, test_size=0.20, stratify=y, random_state=0)

#Trigram_tfidf
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer #to convert the nextual data to numeric data with some weightings to classify it, becuase convert it to documented matrix it will not be accurate so TfidfVectorizer provides some basics to let the machine understaning the to words after counts words process through it 
tfidf_vectorizer_3 = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english',max_df=0.8, ngram_range= (1,3))
tfidf_train_3 = tfidf_vectorizer_3.fit_transform(x_train)
tfidf_test_3 = tfidf_vectorizer_3.transform(x_test) 

#Build machine learning model
#passive aggressive classifire for Trigram:
from sklearn.linear_model import PassiveAggressiveClassifier,LogisticRegression
pass_tf_trigram=PassiveAggressiveClassifier()
pass_tf_trigram.fit(tfidf_train_3,y_train)

pickle.dump(pass_tf_trigram, open("model2.pkl", "wb"))
```

app.py

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle
#import Deploying

# Create flask app
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open("deploy\model2.pkl", "rb"))

@flask_app.route("/")
def Home():
    return render_template("index.html")

@flask_app.route("/predict", methods = ["POST"])
def predict():
    txt_features = [str(x) for x in request.form.values()]
    features = [np.array(txt_features)]
    prediction = model.predict(features)
    return render_template("index.html", prediction_text = "The flower species is {}".format(prediction))



if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(debug=False)
```